# Width 100% goes outside the wrap

Tags: css, width, footer

Width 100% is not working! My footer is going outside the `#wrap` and I don't want to set exact pixels to it.

Any solution?

[live example](http://jsfiddle.net/2P6KR/).

```css
#wrap {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  clear: both;
  display: table;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

footer {
  clear: both;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<div id=wrap>
  <footer>&copy; 2013 PUAction&nbsp;&middot;&nbsp;<a href="#">Terms</a>&nbsp;&middot;&nbsp;<a href="#">Disclaimer</a>&nbsp;&middot;&nbsp;<a href="#">Privacy</a>&nbsp;&middot;&nbsp;<a href="#">Login</a></footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the default box-model behavior :

```
Width = width + padding-left + padding-right + border-left + border-right
```

Therefore, your width is 100% + 2*10px which is larger than the footer's width...

You can :

1. Remove `width: 100%` which will result on an implicit use of `width: auto` (which is just fine because **block elements automatically fill the width of their parent**)
2. Use the `box-sizing: border-box` properties

For deeper explanations, just take a look at this [resource](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/) and [this one](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)!

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You're using display:table on the container. That means the direct child (in this case "footer") should be display:table-cell.

Comment: I have updated the footer to :

   display: table-cell; and still not working

Comment: You don't need the float on a 100% width element. Remove it. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `width: 100%;` that doesn't include the padding, so you have `width:100%` + `padding: 10px` that gives you 100% + 20px width.

A simple solution is to add `box-sizing: border-box;`

```
footer { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2P6KR/6/)

Comment: Still going outside the wrap in your example

Comment: Yep forgot to add the moz prefix, see it now.

Comment: I think this a wrong approach. His semantics are wrong. When he uses proper semantic approach, the problem is automatically fixed without the use of a new box-sizing method.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect !

Thanks guys !

```
box-sizing: border-box;

-moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2P6KR/9/

Comment: Thanks, I had indeed forgotten FF prefix!